# Value from select gets saved into database with quotation marks

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my laravel project I have a select in one view, that looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="custom_field.type" required="" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select Type</option>
   <option value="text">Text</option>
   <option value="dropdown">Dropdown</option>
   <option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
</select>
```

And in my php controller I send the value like this:

```
$input = \Input::get('custom_field');
$custom_field->type= $input['type'];
```

In my migration I declared it like this:

```
$table->string('type');
```

But even thought I send multiple inputs using the same method, in this particular case the value gets saved with quotation marks. I need to strip those quotes. I already tried like this:

```
$custom_field->type= str_replace('"', "", $input['type']);
```

[image: This is how my database looks like]

Thank you all for your time and help!

Comment: Please post the result of `dd($request->custom_field);`

Comment: You could `trim($input['type'], '\"')`

Comment: It looks like you're double quoting your values, so you're probably inserting incorrectly. What does your insert code look like?